# Can I see ALL deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, recently-deleted

For some reason https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last2days is only showing me the most recent 45 posts (about 20 minutes worth), and it only shows posts not deleted by owner.

Is it possible to see *all* deleted posts for the last two days, not just those past 20 minutes and not just those that were deleted by someone other than the OP?

Comment: To the readers of the future: you can get the list of all deleted questions with a singleline query on the https://data.stackexchange.com . However, you can see their content only if you have 10k+ on that site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the lists on the [links](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=links) page is [Recently Deleted Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/recently-deleted). The name is a bit of a misnomer -- it includes all deleted posts (so it's over 30000 pages now)